# Generate CSV in memory from Kendo Grid (MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I'd like to be able to take a kendo grid of data and from that, generate a .csv in memory which I can manipulate and save as I like. So far I've only seen how to export to excel and save directly to disk.

Is there a way to do this? I'm looking specifically for an MVC implementation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a ".csv in memory"?  You can certainly save off the datasource of a kendo grid in a session object, database record, etc.

Comment: Whatever data you use as a data source for your Kendo grid, you can use  to generate a CSV file as well. This question doesn't have anything to do with Kendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-grid-to-csv) is what you are searching for. Basically you can grab the idea and modify it based on your needs.